# Infinite scrolling with partial returns entire layout instead of appending partial Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement an infinite scroll function with a Rails partial, but when the script runs, it loads the entire `application.html.erb` layout instead of just appending the partial. How can I make it append the partial so the page displays properly?

This should be a pretty easy fix, but I'm missing something obvious.

**views/home/index.html.erb**

```
<ol id="scroll-container">
  <%= render :partial => "stories/partial123", :collection => @stories,
:as => :story %>
</ol>
<div id="pages">
  <%= paginate @stories, :remote => true %>
</div>
```

**views/stories/_partial123.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <div id="individual_story">...</div>
</li>
```

I'm using the Kaminari gem to paginate, so I get something like `/?page=2` for the next page link.

**controllers/home_controller.rb**

```
def index
  # Kaminari pagination
  @stories = stories.newest.page(params[:page]).per(5)

respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html { render :action => "index" }
  format.json { render :json => @stories }
end
```

end

After looking at countless tutorials and SO answers, it looked like I needed something like the following `index.js`, but I can't seem to get this working. Am I on the right track? Why won't it execute this code?

**views/home/index.js.erb**

```
$('#scroll-container').html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => "stories/partial123", :collection => @stories,
:as => :story) %>');
$('#pages').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate (@stories, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

For reference, I'm also using Infinite jQuery Scroll [link](http://www.responsivewebmobile.com/posts/view/2013/07/09/19/Responsive_Infinite_Scroll_Tutorial_Template_free) to load the JQuery elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the Kaminari gem works exactly, but it sounds as if everything was working without the `index.js.erb` template except for the unnecessary layouts? If so, try passing a `layout: false` option to `render` for Ajax requests, e.g.:

```
format.html do
  render action: "index", layout: !request.xhr?
end
```

Comment: I had tried doing that already, but without the `!request.xhr?`. That was what I needed. Thanks!